# How to get a list of child nodes and iterate over them

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

My question is **how do I obtain the children nodes for a parent node**. My reason for doing this is I have two elements that have the same tag
and I want to display all the elements for the children nodes. I am new to XML Parsing so I don't know that much, I have been using a DOM Parser.

I have the following xml file

```
<Employees>
    <Employee id=12121>
        <Name> John </Name>
        <Profession> Programmer </Profession>
        <Age> 26 </Age>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id=121212>
        <Name> Jack </Name>
        <Profession> Analyst </Profession>
        <Profession> Team Lead </Profession>
        <Age/> 
    </Employee>
    <Employee id=121241>
        <Name> Emma </Name>
        <Profession> Risk Analyst </Profession>
        <Age> 29 </Age>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to get a list of the children  nodes for each Employee node

I have tried the following code in java

```
/*The code above simple creates a DOM Builder I havent included it in*/
NodeList nList = dc.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++){
    Node nNode = nList.item(i);
    NodeList childNodeList = nNode.getChildNodes();


}
```

The Sample output looks this

```
John profession is Programmer and is aged 26
Jack profession is Analyst and  team lead
Emma profession is Risk Analyst and is aged 29
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good.Whats your doubt?

try this, n1 is the NodeList

```
    for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
        Node n=nl.item(i);
        if(n.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
           System.out.println(n.getNodeName()+"\t"+n.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I display the elements in the childNodeList I cant get that to work.

Comment: that did help a lot but how do I remove the parentNode from display